# How to change the default import hint in VSCode from ES6 to commonjs?

Tags: typescript-typings, visual-studio-code

I've a small piece of JavaScript that I open on Visual Studio Code, I then enable `@ts-check` to get type hinting from `TypeScript` definition files.

When I refer to a type that comes from a different import VSCode will give the hint and add the following code to the beginning of the file:

```
import { SomeType } from 'some-module';
```

This is correct if I'm working on ES6 but currently I'm targetting to older runtimes and would prefer to get the generated code be written using the `commonjs` syntax:

```
var SomeType = require('some-module').SomeType;
```

Is there any configuration I can change to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation. I've been able to get rid of type errors but I can't seem to figure out how to get code completion to list 'require' or 'module.exports' in its options.

To get ride of type error messages.

{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es2015"
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }